# eclipse update sites: HTTP Proxy Authentication Required error

Tags: eclipse, proxy

when I go to Install new software and select an update site, I get a "HTTP Proxy Authentication Required" error.

I have searched the internets for quite some time, and I still did not get an answer.

Facts:

- I get this error for every update site.
- I am able to access the update site link both in an internal or external browser.
- I am using the "native" proxy in eclipse network settings.
- direct proxy in eclipse network settings does not work either.
- our helpdesk told me that it's not possible to set up the manual proxy in eclipse network settings (or they don't know)
- I've tried manually inserting a proxy server:port that I found in a proxy.pac file that I've discovered, no luck...
- I've tried reinstalling Eclipse, re-adding and/or reloading repositories and deleting repo cache dir
- I'm using: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in ini file
- I've tried mirroring the repositories using both methods, but log file gives the same proxy error

My system:
Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600
Windows 7, 64bit

Answer (score 58):

Just add this at the end of your `eclipse.ini` :

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

In my case I had to set the proxy also to manual (SOCKS should be unchecked). But then, no more hassle.

It basically disables the default Apache HTTP client and will use an HTTP client based on the JRE URL connection.
See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient

**Edit:**

There is a new Apache HTTP client version for which the parameter value has changed:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45
```

To disable both use:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Comment: Thanks bro! This worked for me on a ForeFront TMG Proxy!

Comment: This helped me to solve "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" problem while trying to install a new plugin through eclipse marketplace, thank you.

Comment: what is this option doing?

Comment: Where to do ? i am getting this error while installing itself. In which place exactly do i need to add these ?

Comment: Wow, that did the trick for me too. What an obscure fix ... [Using Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)]. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I could solve the same problem by going to `"Windows"` → `"Preferences"` → `"Network Connections"` and set `"Active Provider"` to `"Direct"`. See more details and a screenshot in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42691498/2885656).

Comment: Works fine for me in Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Answer (score 4):

1. Switch to the manual proxy options
2. Enter your proxy, user and password
3. Do it for al except SOCKS. SOCKS you may leave empty.

I've tried a lot of solutions in Google, but nothing :( 
I was going to forget about eclipse, but suddenly it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I talked to a guy who manages the proxy settings in our company and luckily he did some changes to the proxy server and now I'm able to install addons & update software from within eclipse :-)

Answer (score 0):

For my proxy settings, I HAD to leave SOCKS proxy configuration empty after entering manual proxy settings for both HTTP and HTTPS.
Leaving them all empty didn't work, and filling them all out didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using this in eclipse.ini:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Source: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient45

Comment: _Note:_ This is basically the same answer as @ViToni's above, but updated based on the latest version of the Apache HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse through a virtual machine, then set the network settings to manual in Eclipse. That should solve the issue.