# Eclipse Neon HTTP Proxy Authentication Required Error

Tags: eclipse, proxy

When I go to "Install new software" and select an update site or 
go to "Available Software Site" and click "Reload", I get a "HTTP Proxy Authentication Required" error.

I have searched the web, and I've tried the found suggestion like setting `eclipse.ini` with

```
-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

I set the Neon link in an Helios version and it show the Available Software wihtout error.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon

HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/compositeContent.xml
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/compositeContent.xml
Proxy Authentication Required

I've not config Eclipse to authenticate against any proxy.

Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Windows 7 64bit

How can I set it to work?
I'm inside a company netword but I have also tried in my home with the same Laptop and the problem persist.

Comment: Did you read http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm ?

Comment: Yes, I have done. I let these config as default. Helios connect fine.

Answer (score 16):

Solve it adding to eclipse.ini

```
Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

and removing:

```
Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Worked under Eclipse Oxygen (v.4.7.0) like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with my `Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2)`. I had no success whatsoever by specifying `-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4` in the `eclipse.ini`, as proposed here and in [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968836/eclipse-update-sites-http-proxy-authentication-required-error) on StackOverflow. The only thing that helped me was to do the following. Go to `"Windows"` → `"Preferences"` → `"General"` → `"Network Connections"` and set `"Active Provider"` to `"Direct"`, then confirm the new settings. After this I could successfully use Eclipse software update sites, as I wanted. All in all, my settings look like this:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me using Eclipse Oxygen.  The path is a little different.  I used Windows - Preferences - General - Network Connections.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard True, this path is also visible in the screenshot. I will fix this in the answer, thanks for paying attention.

Comment: Works fine for me in Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the software manually on eclipse, find a zip file online.

Go to Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive and locate the zip file.

Make sure to untick the box "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" because if this is ticked it will give the "HTTP Proxy Authentication Required"