# Knime Install Extensions fails: HTTP Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: eclipse, knime

I am using Knime on a remote desktop location and run it there in my local workspace on the other computer, I needed ot change my password and afterwards I cannot install updates again. Now I get the following error:

```
Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://update.knime.com/community-contributions/trusted/3.7/content.xml
Proxy Authentication Required
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://update.knime.com/analytics-platform/3.7/content.xml
Proxy Authentication Required
```

I followd this thread here: [Eclipse Neon HTTP Proxy Authentication Required Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576290/eclipse-neon-http-proxy-authentication-required-error/42691498#42691498)

But this does not work out for me, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own, under Help--> Install Software I need to exclude every update path which was not refereing to my local zip file