# Mule - Project build failed when running with maven

Tags: java, maven, mule

I'm getting a failure trying to run a Hello World Mulesoft project, it looks like it related to the version of Mulesoft that I'm running, I googled around but I couldn't get any info to help resolve this issue, here is the build error:

```
[10:01:21] Running: mvn clean package -DskipMunitTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mule firsttest Application 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.8.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jdbc-ee:jar:3.8.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jms-ee:jar:3.8.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.496 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-31T10:01:27-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "compiler" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project firsttest: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.schwab:firsttest:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.4: Failure to find org.mule.transports:mule-transports:pom:3.8.4 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

### Here is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.schwab</groupId>
    <artifactId>firsttest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule firsttest Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.8.4</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository> 
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository> 
    </repositories> 
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

---

Any idea of what's going on?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Additional details: Apache Maven 3.5.0 
Maven home: C:\MuleSoftwares\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 1):

Maven cannot find `transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.4` as it is not available in the Mule Maven repository configured in your pom under `<repositories>`. This is the Public Mule repository, but it seems the 3.8.4 runtime and its dependencies were not made public, probably only available for Enterprise users. You can see for yourself by browsing the repository, the JAR is missing: https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-file/3.8.4

You can either use Mule 3.8.1 for which your dependency is available (change Mule version in your pom) or configure the Enterprise (EE) repository if you have proper license and access (see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb)

*Not related note: it seems you are running Mule EE inside Studio. Studio provide EE runtime for testing purposes, so Maven does not complain (too much) about missing EE dependencies, but if you try to run Mule EE outside Studio you will need to configure the EE repository. *

Comment: Thanks for the details, I tried installing 3.8.1 run time but I get:                    HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/content.xml.xz
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/content.xml.xz
Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: When did you have this error? When installing from Studio or when running Maven? If it's when you are trying to install the runtime via Studio Update installer it may be caused by your proxy config. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968836/eclipse-update-sites-http-proxy-authentication-required-error

Answer (score 0):

Update Setting.xml with Proxy details,if you are trying from organisation network, it seems it is not able to download all the jars

Comment: The proxy problem is when I try to use Mule install, there is no maven at this point, I restarted my Mule 2 times and I was able to download the run time, something wrong with my proxy (firewall) at my company. when I try to install again it gives a proxy error again, I might have to speak to someone on the proxy team to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is your first project. You can disable Maven in order to experience MULE behavior. Right Click on the project and it provides an option to disable Maven. After that you can run your project.

Comment: That's true, my first Mule project, maven was disabled, I was getting the error when trying to install through Mule only. see my replies above..